# Rcpp: Append rows to dataframe by reference

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am passing a dataframe by reference and trying to add columns to it. My plan is to append rows to it this way.

My code so far is given below and compiles without errors with `sourceCpp` - however, I can't execute the function like this:

```
lst <- list("a"=c("aone", "atwo"), "b"=c("bone","btwo"))
mainFunc(lst)
```

This tells me that `mainFunc` is undefined, so I suspect that the code is incorrect somehow:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;


class C
{
public:
  void test(Rcpp::DataFrame& df, Rcpp::List y)
  {

    int n = y.size();
    for( int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
      List sublist = y[i];
      int m = sublist.size();
      for(int j = 0; j<m; ++j)
      {
        CharacterVector sublist_element = sublist[j];

        df[sublist_element] = sublist_element;
      }
    }

  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<C> mainFunc(Rcpp::List y)
{
  XPtr<C> ptr(new C(), true);

  DataFrame df;

  ptr->test(df, y);
  return(ptr);
}
```

So is it possible to create a dataframe in `mainFunc` and add/append values to it in `mainFunc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered before as well but I don't have the reference handy.  In essence:

- a `data.frame` is a list of vectors
- at the C++ level you *just* see a set of vectors
- so you essentially have to insert into each vector
- and resize as needed

Resizing is *expensive* as you need to reallocate and copy content so if you know you have, say, ten rows to insert only do it once.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Is it more efficient to use a `List` instead of a `data.frame` then? Or some native structure to C++ that I convert? I don't know the final size beforehand :-(

Comment: When we do this (see eg in Rblpapi) we often grow `std::vector` row by row and at the end convert and create a `data.frame`.

Comment: I'm looking through the source-files of Rblpapi now, but there are quite a few - can you point me to one where this conversion happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example does not make a lot of sense.  Why do you need `XPtr`?  Have you looked at the [DataFrameExample](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/DataFrameExample.cpp) ?

Comment: Would you mind posting a quick example of this? I think a lot of people who end up here are R users struggling to learn c++ in the context of rcpp. An example of iterating through the full length of multiple vectors and manipulating them would be greatly appreciated. The datafame example on the RCPP website doesn't teach people how to treat multiple vectors as a single row.

Comment: There are eight vignettes including two published papers that come with the package. There are over one-hundred examples at the Rcpp Gallery.  There are over 1500 packages at CRAN using Rcpp.  There are almost 2000 question here so no, sorry, I don;t have the bandwidth to add on-demand examples in a comment thread on a 15 months old question. Why don't you ask a question _with proper context_ on the rcpp-devel list?  Also, we write it as Rcpp.  Not 'rcpp' and not 'RCPP'.